# When I import torchvision, I get an error that the cuda version of pytorch and torchvision are different

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pytorch

I am getting the following error when importing torchvision.

```
Detected that PyTorch and torchvision were compiled with different CUDA versions. PyTorch has CUDA Version=11.0 and torchvision has CUDA Version=10.1. Please reinstall the torchvision that matches your PyTorch install.
```

How can I change the cuda version of pytorch to 10.1?

'conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1-c pytorch' from anaconda prompt
I get the same error even if I do it.

I am using windows10, and I am using python version 3.7 in the virtual environment of jupyter notebook.

Comment: `cudatoolkit=10.1-c pytorch`, is that a typo?

Comment: Is there something wrong? Even if it says 'conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1-c pytorch', it was installed.

Comment: You might not be able to install it with a different version because it's already installed. Maybe try to uninstall it with `conda uninstall pytorch torchvision` and install it back with `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch`.

Comment: I haven't thought about deleting and reinstalling. Doing the same as you told me, solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling and installing it back might work

```
!conda uninstall pytorch torchvision
```

With:

```
!conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```